# How to fix the position of `<select>` of bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, position

Html code:

```
<button class="btn">hello</button>
<select class="input-small"><option>1</option></select>
<button class="btn">world</button>
```

But the position of `select` is not correct. You can see the live demo from http://jsfiddle.net/SUJpH/

I have to add a fix for it:

```
select {
    position: relative;
    bottom: -4px;
}
```

It works but I wonder if there is some css classes provided by bootstrap can fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add tag `form` with class `form-inline`:

```
<form class="form-inline"> 
    <button class="btn">hello</button>
    <select class="input-small"><option>1</option></select>
    <button class="btn">world</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You actually do not need it to be a `<form>` tag, it can be a `<div>` : http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/SUJpH/6/

Answer (score 0):

In **bootstrap.css** line no. - 951 in this class -

```
select, textarea, input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="datetime"], input[type="datetime-local"], input[type="date"], input[type="month"], input[type="time"], input[type="week"], input[type="number"], input[type="email"], input[type="url"], input[type="search"], input[type="tel"], input[type="color"], .uneditable-input
```

There is `margin-bottom: 9px;`

remove that and everything will work as expected

Comment: I wouldn't recommend modifying the original css file.

Answer (score 0):

an approach which leaves `bootstrap.css` unchanged is to write it like this:

```
<select class="input-small" style="margin-top:10px"><option>1</option></select>
```